# How to prevent CI automation failures due to missing ssh key fingerprints?

Tags: git, bash, ssh

It is known that adding `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to ssh opens a big MITM security hole. Still when doing automation we do want to avoid breaking the build because we are not running on interactive mode.

It seems that `StrictHostKeyChecking` has only 3 modes, none of them being able to cover the case where you want to auto-accept unknown keys if they are no conflicts.

- `ask`: doesn't work with automation
- `no`: enables MITM, serious security concerns
- `yes`: will not work if the fingerprint is not already known

So, how we can make this work in automation, auto-learning new keys but failing if they do not match existing ones?

Answer (score 0):

> So, how we can make this work in automation, auto-learning new keys but failing if they do not match existing ones?

This is basically effective to the `no` option, when the first public key is from some man-in-the-middle.

You should get the initial key over different secure channel and store it in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. One possibility is to use SSH certificates and trust the certificate authority, not the single keys.

The other possibility, if you don't mind the initial key setup, is to use `ssh-keyscan`, which will fetch the keys from server and store them in the `known_hosts`:

```
ssh-keyscan host >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Then using `StrictHostKeyChecking yes` will do exactly what you need.